# Showing the virtual hosts and switches in RYU GUI

Tags: python

I am using Ryu SDN controller with Open vSwitches. And I want to run the Ryu GUI. I have used the gui_topology API and my simple_switch file. It works fine, but the GUI shows only the switches connected to the controller but not the virtual hosts connected to the switch. Any idea how can I show the hosts too? Or do I need to use something other than gui_topology to see both switch and hosts?

Any help is appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: I used RYU a long time ago . But my rough guess would be that you will need to generate some traffic for the host to get learnt on the RYU controller

Comment: Will do that, thank you alot!